# Помогите обратиться к елементу списка Python

Tags: python, tkinter, for

У меня есть код, в котором в окне Tkinter`а цикл выводит название всех файлов в папке в фрейм.
Но я хотел также добавить кнопки удаления и открытия этих файлов.
Но я не знаю как обратиться к конкретному елементу, ведь каждый созданый фрейм - это отдельная итерация цикла For.
код цикла:

```
        self.arrcount =0
        self.blocksCounter = 0
        self.Height = 0.05
        for i in range(self.file_count):
            self.videoBlock = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame1, bg=self.darkColour)
            self.videoBlock.place(relx=0.01, rely=self.Height, relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.2)
            self.vTitle = tk.Label(self.videoBlock, bg = self.darkColour, fg = self.whitecolour, text = self.count[2][self.arrcount], anchor = tk.W, font = ('Helvetica', 14) )
            self.vTitle.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.7, relheight = 0.2)
            self.openBtn = tk.Button(self.videoBlock, fg = self.darkColour, bg = self.cactive,bd = 0, text = "Open" ,command=self.openfile)
            self.openBtn.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.4, relwidth = 0.1, relheight = 0.25)
            self.deleteBtn = tk.Button(self.videoBlock, bg= 'red', fg = self.whitecolour, text = "X", command = self.removeFile)
            self.deleteBtn.place(relx = 0.94, rely = 0.65, relwidth = 0.05, relheight = 0.3)
            self.Height += 0.22
            self.blocksCounter += 1
            self.arrcount +=1
```

self.file_count - Переменная которая хранит в себе количество файлов в папке
self.count[][] - это список с названием файлов.
Сам список:

> ('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Empty Folder', [], ['Duke Dumont - Ocean Drive (Official Music Video).mp4', 'Joji - SLOW DANCING IN THE DARK.mp4', 'Lana Del Rey - Summertime Sadness (Official Music Video).mp4', 'masquerade.mp4', 'The Weeknd - Call Out My Name (Official Video).mp4'])

Сами фреймы и названия он выводит хорошо, как и все кнопки, но как допустим привязять функционал?
Если попробовать такую функцию:

```
 def removeFile(self):
    self.mes = tk.messagebox.askquestion(title="Warning",icon='warning',message='Do you want to delete this fie?')
    if self.mes == 'yes':
        os.remove(self.count[2][self.arrcount])
        print('File deleted')
    else:
        print('Deleting Canceled')
```

То код выдает ошибку:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `count` или `file_count`?

Comment: Выведите через print что конкретно у вас в self.count. Может у вас там два элемента, а вы обращаетесь к третьему (индекс 2 с учетом 0-го элемента - это третий элемент).

Comment: **Обновил код к вашим коментариям**\n Выкладывать весь код я не смогу посколько програма имеет около 500ста строк кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вижу проблемы передавать имя файла в качестве параметра для функций открытия и удаления.

```
 def removeFile(self, filename):
    self.mes = tk.messagebox.askquestion(title="Warning", icon='warning',
                             message=f'Do you want to delete file "{filename}" ?')
    if self.mes == 'yes':
        os.remove(filename)
        print('File deleted')
    else:
        print('Deleting Canceled')
```

```
        self.arrcount =0
        self.blocksCounter = 0
        self.Height = 0.05
        for i in range(self.file_count):
            self.videoBlock = tk.Frame(self.mainFrame1, bg=self.darkColour)
            self.videoBlock.place(relx=0.01, rely=self.Height, relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.2)
            self.vTitle = tk.Label(self.videoBlock, bg = self.darkColour, fg = self.whitecolour, text = self.count[2][self.arrcount], anchor = tk.W, font = ('Helvetica', 14) )
            self.vTitle.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.7, relheight = 0.2)
            self.openBtn = tk.Button(self.videoBlock, fg = self.darkColour, 
                                     bg = self.cactive,bd = 0, text = "Open", 
                                     command=lambda: self.openfile(self.count[2][self.arrcount]))
            self.openBtn.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.4, relwidth = 0.1, relheight = 0.25)
            self.deleteBtn = tk.Button(self.videoBlock, bg= 'red', 
                                       fg = self.whitecolour, text = "X",
                                       command = lambda: self.removeFile(self.count[2][self.arrcount]))
            self.deleteBtn.place(relx = 0.94, rely = 0.65, relwidth = 0.05, relheight = 0.3)
            self.Height += 0.22
            self.blocksCounter += 1
            self.arrcount +=1
```

Или, если хотите, можете передавать только индекс в списке (`self.arrcount`), раз уж сам список всё равно хранится.
*(Правда я не понимаю зачем делать атрибутами класса локальные счётчики `self.blocksCounter` и `self.arrcount`, и чем они отличаются от переменной `i`)*

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Я  и вправду забыл что в функцию можно так передавать параметры и использовать lambda - функции. Правда только индекс передать никак не получиться ведь список может меняться. Ваше замечание насчет локальных счетчиков тоже оказалось полезным, я сам так и не понял почему я их сделал атрибутами, видимо мне стоит подтянуть свои знания в ООП.